# How to access a Facebook access token after a user has used "log in with Facebook" on an app?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I currently have an app that uses facebook login but after the user has logged in I need access to that token in order to connect to an api the user is logging in to:

```
(GET) /facebook/token/callback?access_token=<access_token>
```

I've tried using `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken`but when I print it out it just reads `(function)` any idea on how to access the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBSDKAccessToken is an object that contains information such as the token string, permissions that were granted, and permissions that were denied. The path you provided was a global access function to the object.

You will want to use the string variable "tokenString" with in the FBSDKAccessToken class.

Comment: You have tried "FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString"?

Comment: FBSDKAccessToken.tokenString  - but I keep getting an error:  Instance member 'tokenString' cannot be used on type 'FBSDKAccessToken'

Comment: That did it! Thanks for you help!